# Multiple if-else within json adaptive card

Tags: json, botframework, adaptive-cards

0

I'm new to adaptive cards and the usage of JSON conditional statements on adaptive cards.

Can I know if it is possible to change the color of an adaptive card text using multiple if-else statements? Such as having 3 color output options.

Also, does if-else statements support in adaptive cards version 1.0?

Below is a sample of code I found from here by asking a question before, however, does the version of the adaptive card affect the output by giving an if condition in the color?

```
{
"type": "AdaptiveCard",
"$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
"version": "1.0",
"body": [
    {            
          "$data": "${AttendanceMonthly}",
          "type": "TextBlock",
          "weight": "bolder",
          "separator": true,
           "color": "${if(WorkedHours < 6, 'attention', 'good')}",
          "text": "Hours worked: ${WorkedHours}"
    }]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can nest the `if/else` statements, like:

```
${if(WorkedHours < 6, 'attention', if(<condition>, <true>, <false>))}"
```

However, you may benefit more from using some other [logical operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-concept-adaptive-expressions?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=logical#operators), depending on what you're trying to accomplish.

I don't recall which version began support of [Adaptive Expression Language](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-concept-adaptive-expressions?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=arithmetic), but you may as well set to version `1.3`, if you can. Note, however, that if you're using cards you created before May 2020, [there might be some breaking changes in data binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/templating/language#breaking-changes-as-of-may-2020).